# Ionic routerLink not redirecting

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am developing an ionic 5 / Angular app and having some trouble navigating from div.

```
<div class="timeline__post" [routerLink]="['/visita',visita.id, 'detalle']">
        <div class="timeline__content" >
          <p><b>{{visita.nombreCliente + ' - ' + visita.nombreEstablecimiento}}</b></p>
          <p><b>Tipo visita: </b>{{visita.tipoVisita}}</p>
          <p><b>Asignado a: </b>{{visita.empleadoAsignado}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

When clicking on this div, the route is updated on first click, but no component is rendered. Clicking second time on any part of the screen produces the component to render correctly.

Navigation from (onclick) event using `this.router.navigate(['/visita',id, 'detalle'])` has been tried and same behavior.

Just in case, this is the routing:

```
  {
    path: ':id/detalle',
    component: VisitaDetalleComponent
  },
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: The router link is working but the component isn't rendering is what you're saying. Does this occur for all of your routes? If not, it's almost certainly something wrong with that component

Comment: Path : visita/:id/detalle

Comment: All components render correctly but two. The one I 've mentioned, and another one that is also being called from a div